# JSTL: How to print a newline

Tags: jstl, el

How can I print a newline ("\n" or "\r\n" or "\n\r"). Which is the right one to be understood by a browser?) using JSTL or EL? I want to really print a newline (not a `<BR>`), since I need to place it in a javascript section in a HTML file.

Comment: If you need to separate two statements in JavaScript, they can be separated with a semi-colon instead of a new line; might be worth a try.

Comment: Actually I need to put a \n after a // <![CDATA[ to end the comemnt before actaul JS code starts.

Comment: This is already the default behaviour. Just put the code which should end up in a new line in a new line of the JSP file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, solution is just not to use JSTL/EL

```
<% out.print("\n"); %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the xml entities for this: `&#10;` for a newline and `&#13;` for carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
<%= '\n' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question in your main post, and you later added it in a comment (perhaps you should edit your post to reflect the information in the comment?):

> I need to put a \n after a // <![CDATA[ to end the comemnt before actaul JS code starts.

The easiest way to fix your issue is to comment out the `CDATA` using a block comment like this:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
```

This will allow you to continue your code on the same line and it will not be part of the comment.

### Example

```
/* <![CDATA[ */ var foo = "var";alert( foo ); /* ]]> */
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below concept and it works.

```
<c:set var="String1" value="line1 line2 line3 line4" />
<c:set var="String2" value="${fn:split(String1, ' ')}" />
<c:set var= "new" value="<br />" />

<c:out value="${String2[0]}${new}" escapeXml="false" />
<c:out value="${String2[1]}${new}" escapeXml="false" />
<c:out value="${String2[2]}${new}" escapeXml="false" />
<c:out value="${String2[3]}${new}" escapeXml="false" />
```